# list of lists of which the sum is within a given range (homework)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, combinations

I want to define a function that takes the following arguments: 
-a list of numbers
-a minimum
-a maximum

It should return a list of lists (or sets) of which the sum of each list is between the minimum and the maximum. There should be no duplicates in a list.

What I've got does not return all possible lists:

```
def givelists(List, minimum, maximum):
    currentlist = [] #list to keep track of sum of currently included subset of list
    listoflist = [] #list of all lists of which the sum is between specified minumum and maximum
    for number in List:
        if minimum < (sum(currentlist) + number) < maximum:
            currentlist.append(number)
            listoflist.append(currentlist)
            currentlist = []
        elif (sum(currentlist) + number) < minimum:
            currentlist.append(number)
        else:
            if number in range(minimum, maximum):
                listoflist.append(number)
    return(listoflist)
```

For example:

```
givelists(list(range(1,6)), 2, 8)

# Output: [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: What result do you expect? Test it with `range(1,2), 1, 1`. What would you expect?

Comment: For the output of your example, I would have said [ [3], [4], [5], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [2,3]..... ]
which are all the possibles combinations to have  sums between 2 and 8.
So can you re-formulate the expected output ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider Multiple combinations of the numbers in the list, like;

```
for every number in the list:
    test if that number is a feasible solution
    for every other number in the list:
        test if they can be grouped with that number \
        and produce a feasible solution # (recursion here)
```

so Mainly your code should look like this

```
def sums_in_range(lst, min, max):
    result = []
    for i, number in enumerate(lst):
        if min < number < max:
            result.append([number])
        candidates = sums_in_range(
            [test for test in lst[i+1:] if test < max-number], min-number, max-number)
        for candidate in candidates:
            result.append([number]+candidate)
    return result

print(sums_in_range(sorted(list(range(1, 6))), 2, 8))
```

**NOTES**:

- I'm doing `i+1` in `lst[i+1:]` so it doesn't return lists with duplicates like `[1, 1, 1]`
- I'm doing `lst[i+1:]` so it doesn't calculate duplicates like `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`
- `sorted` to take negative values into account, see the comments

**EDIT**

For the sake of completeness(and i had some free time), if you want to take things much further

I've made a comparison between the 3 answers posted here, memory and time wise on the same data

and you can find the code to reproduce the results [here](https://gist.github.com/MahmoudFarouq/e7d756e88938f2891f04fe8111bf2791)

and this was the results i came up with

[image]

the test input was

```
test_lst = list(range(1, 25))
test_min = 2
test_max = 50
```

Comment: The condition `test < max - number` assumes the numbers are non-negative; for example, `sums_in_range([2, 3, -3], 1, 3)` returns `[[2]]`, which is missing `[2, 3, -3]` with the same sum.

Comment: @kaya3 Thats rights, i didn't test it against negative values so thanks for your note, the `test < max - number` is a hack to reduce the number of recursion branches, however `sorting` the incoming list solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset_sum(iterable, minimum, maximum):
    s = set(iterable)
    combs = chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
    valid_combs = [list(comb) for comb in combs if (minimum < sum(comb) < maximum)]
    return valid_combs
print(powerset_sum(list(range(1,6)), 2, 8))
```

Output:

```
[[3],
 [4],
 [5],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [1, 5],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [2, 5],
 [3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The disadvantage here however is that it get computationally very heavy with a larger input list and a larger min-max interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution which doesn't use imported modules:

```py
def get_lists_in_range(lst, minimum, maximum):
    result = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        #print(i, item, lst[i+1:])
        all_lists = get_lists_in_range(lst[i+1:], minimum, maximum)
        if minimum <= item <= maximum:
            result.append([item])
        for l in all_lists:
            if minimum <= item + sum(l) <= maximum:
                result.append([item] + l)           
    return result

print(get_lists_in_range(list(range(1, 6)), 2, 8))
```

Comment: Ok, I was 10 mins too late :)

Comment: It doesn't return all lists though.

Comment: You were right, there was a bug. I think I got rid of it. Still, Mahmoud showed that this solution is not efficient: I don't reduce the minimum/maximum values in the recursion, and always have to double-check if the sum of the item and the new list is within bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive generator function which does a [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search), with some optimisations. Begin by sorting the list, and computing the sums of positive and negative numbers after each index; these can be used as bounds on the sums that can be made with the remaining elements. This gives correct answers for lists containing negative numbers. As a side-effect of sorting the list, the subsets are found in lexicographic order.

Usually a generator function is more useful for combinatorial problems than returning all the results in a list, since there could be a very large number of solutions and you don't usually need them all in memory at once. However, `yield` is a bit slower than `append`, so if you always want the results in a list, I've shown the appropriate changes to make using comments.

```py
def subsets_sum_in_range(lst, min_s, max_s):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    n = len(lst)
    pos_sums = [0] * (n + 1)
    neg_sums = [0] * (n + 1)
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        pos_sums[i] = pos_sums[i+1] + max(0, lst[i])
        neg_sums[i] = neg_sums[i+1] + min(0, lst[i])

    def helper(i, s, t):
        if min_s <= s <= max_s:
            yield t
            # out.append(t)
        for j in range(i, n):
            if s + pos_sums[j] < min_s or s + neg_sums[j] > max_s:
                break
            v = lst[j]
            yield from helper(j + 1, s + v, t + (v,))
            # helper(j + 1, s + v, t + (v,))

    return helper(0, 0, ())
    # out = []
    # helper(0, 0, ())
    # return out
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(subsets_of_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3, 6))
[(1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 5),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (5,)]
```